# typescript generic type guard

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, casting

I have variable that can be either of type `C1[]` or `C2<C1>[]` how do I create a type guard  for the variable?

```
interface C<T>{
   key: string;
   secret: T;
}

private isC(d: Foo[] | C<Foo>): d is C<Foo>[] {
    return (<C<Foo>>)d[0].key !== undefined
}
```

The method `isC` is not compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues, here:

1. The `isC` function needs `Foo` as a type parameter. This means it needs to be declared like this:

   ```
   private isC<Foo>(...
   ```
2. The return type definition of `isC` does not match its input parameters. The return type declares that `isC` returns `true`, when its parameter `d` is of Type `C<Foo>[]`, but the input type is restricted to `Foo[]` or `C<Foo>` (neither of them being `C<Foo>[]`).

   This declaration should work:

   ```
   private isC<Foo>(d: Foo[] | C<Foo>[]): d is C<Foo>[] { ...
   ```
3. `(<C<Foo>>)d[0]` is not a valid type cast. Try this, instead:

   ```
   return (d as C<Foo>[])[0].key !== undefined
   ```

Also see this [playground with compiling example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20C%3CT%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20key%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20secret%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isC%3CFoo%3E(d%3A%20Foo%5B%5D%20%7C%20C%3CFoo%3E%5B%5D)%3A%20d%20is%20C%3CFoo%3E%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(d%20as%20C%3CFoo%3E%5B%5D)%5B0%5D.key%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A).

Answer (score 0):

```
private isC(d: Foo[] | C<Foo>): d is C<Foo>[] {
    return (d as C<Foo>[])[0].key !== undefined
}
```